# Black box test plan to see whether a value is hard coded

Tags: hardcode, manual-testing, hardcoded, black-box-testing, test-plan

I need to make a manual test plan (black box testing) to see whether a value is hard coded in a drop down list (its' the acceptance criteria).
Can anybody give me any suggestions on that?

Thanks in advance
Saj

Answer (score 0):

Until you will describe your application a bit more is hard to say something.

If you can using adming priviliges add/remove values on the dropdown then test is simple.

However if not, if any functionality do not allow you to change values on the DDL why test it then? 
The requirment should be descoped as part of Test Report abrevation from Test Plan with given resonable why it is not tested, why it cannot be tested in black box methodology and approved by Product Owner or bussines users.

Answer (score 0):

if the data of the drop down list is taken from data base u can change the data from the data base and check the hard code issue or else

As per the unique id the data is populated in the drop down u can change that unique id and identify is there any hard cord.

Answer (score 0):

There at at least three options:

1. If you have possibility to change values in that list by making something in the application just try it
2. If not - perhaps you have possibility to add something to the list
3. If not - maybe you have to the database and can change the data
4. If not - ask someone - maybe administrator can make some changes in database for a short time - just to make some test.

Take into account that changing in application and in database may not look the same - when you change in application everything should work, changing in database may require some other actions (triggers, procedures) or time (some things may be refreshed during night or in other schedule).